What would it take to unlock Phobos or Deimos?
Phobos and Deimos do librate, like Earth's moon does. That slight pendulum motion could be exacerbated with minimal torque applied periodically, similar to impulses on a swing or a balance wheel in a mechanical watch. Is this correct and what/how long would it take to do so? Probably false assumption/fantasy behind this is : if Mars' moon start rotating, instead of being synchronous, it could anchor a practical skyhook.

I think this is an interesting question! What would it take to give one of the moons an average rotational period that is not a small rational number multiple of it's orbital period, and I why is it important to avoid small rational multiples? (e.g. 3/2, 2/5, etc.) Would it be possible to apply torque without destroying the moon itself? Could it be done wth a giant billboard painted black on one side and white on the other? I think the down and close votes are premature - seems quite answerable to me.

@uhoh unsure how to math it, but the spin up might be achievable with the sky hook structure itself acting as a sail - what I'm less clear on is do you end up de-orbiting your chosen moon before it gets your desired spin, since the spin energy is coming from the orbital velocity

Slightly lateral thinking--if you're building a megastructure on Phobos, maybe the megastructure itself can rotate without the moon having to?  Presumably Phobos is still the more massive of the two, and could accommodate some kind of circumferential track.  I couldn't tell you for certain, but my initial guess is definitely that it trades favorably against spinning all of Phobos.

@uhoh and this would definitely tell which direction one Crookes radiometer spins in a perfect vacuum

@ErinAnne I'd have thought building a circular monorail around that potatoïd moon, would become a "larger" megaproject than spinning the whole thing. (because I'm unable to grasp what it takes to alter that massive object's rotation rate)

@GremlinWranger no idea how that sky hook structure acting as a sail could transmit torque to the moonlet. But if it does using solar wind, energy should come from that and not from orbital velocity (?)

@user721108 if you build down from a locked moon into the atmosphere, the drag forces at the tip will tend to start rotation (hold a pen or stick in the middle and move it across a bucket of water), and be opposed by flex in the structure and tidal forces. Unclear on how to math out which wins for a given design, but suspect unreasonable amount of stiffness would probably required (eg repeat above pen over water test with a string in place of the pen).

@GremlinWranger I agree if that construction extends into Mars' atmosphere it will pull the whole system down, shrinking that moonlet's orbit

@user721108 not as much as you'd think. If you applied a drag force on the center of mass of the moon plus structure, yes. But it sounds like the center of mass would still be up near the moon and so the atmospheric drag on the structure would mostly be applying a torque on the center of mass, not a force.

@uhoh gathering that torque from atmospheric drag looks painful, while having only one shorter cable reeled in and out at the correct pace, could boost libration without atmospheric interaction, therfore not altering moonlet's orbit (using only tidal (de)stabilisation that ulimately gains centrifugal consistency, if this makes sense at all

@user721108 OK, I don't have a horse in this race - any "geoengineering" endeavor will be challenging. To show that that method would actually work, I think it's necessary to run a simulation, solve the problem analytically, or cite a previous scholarly source where that's already been done. Personally, the idea of making a moon spin makes my head spin :-)

@user721108 as as side note "Phobos and Deimos do librate, like Earth's moon does" is not wrong, but it's misleading. There are  two kinds of libration. The first is what we easily see in the Moon - because the rotation is almost uniform but the orbit is very eliptical, there is an apparent libration because the orbital rate increases and decreases while the rotation rate is almost constant. The Moon does have a physical libration (actual non-uniform rotation) but it's tiny, a few seconds of arc. The martian moons still have large physical libration because they are tiny.
